# why here Twice run program

Tags: python, python-3.x, open-source

```
class password:
    def pas1():
        pas = []
        tedad = int(input('how many do you have information ? '))

        for i in range(1,tedad):
            b=input('enter : ')
            pas.append(b)

        print('this is your pas ---> {}' . format(pas))

import nnk
me=nnk.password.pas1()
```

why here Twice run `pas1` . i want once run `def pas1()` and next go to next line . here twice ask me `how many do you have information ?`  and twice `ask me enter :`

Comment: please be clearer on what help you need and what is `nnk`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues with Code :**

Object creation is not correct for password class. 
also argument self is not passed to class method .

**Fixed Code**

```
class password:

    def pas1(self):
        pas = []
        tedad = int(input('how many do you have information ? :  '))

        for i in range(1,tedad):
            b=input('enter : ')
            pas.append(b)

        print('this is your pas ---> {}' . format(pas))


me=password()
me.pas1()
```

**Output**

```
how many do you have information ? :  12
enter : 2
enter : 2
enter : 3
enter : 4
enter : 5
enter : 6
enter : 6
enter : 7
enter : 8
enter : 9
enter : 4
this is your pas ---> ['2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '6', '7', '8', '9', '4']
```